# Get rid of default extra padding for Texts in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, user-interface, text, android-jetpack-compose, size

**I can't find a way for such a simple change**:

`Texts` in `jetpack compose` have a default **padding** on `top` and `bottom` like this:

[image]

***How can I remove that***?
I want the border of the `Text Composable` to be at the `top` and `bottom` end of the letters, *just like it is the case on the right and the left of the text*

If I use `Modifier.height()`, letters like `g` get cut off, but I want them to still be visible while other Composables like `Column` ignore those extra heights

---

After setting deprecated `includeFontPadding` to false, the padding amount gets decreased, but still exists:

[image]

---

**How can that padding be reduced to zero?**

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you are using an old version of Compose? This issue was fixed in [Version 1.2.0-alpha05](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.2.0-alpha05): "Text: includeFontPadding is now turned off by default." Try upgrading to version 1.3.3.

EDIT: It looks like it was turned on again in [1.2.0-beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.2.0-beta01). According to the [issueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171394808#comment65): "RelNote: "Turned on default includeFontPadding. It is possible to
turn off the includeFontPadding using TextStyle.platformTextStyle
attribute. In the near future we will change the default behavior
however until that time this allows us to better integrate line height
improvements (aosp/2058653) and solve TextField clipping issues."

The workaround is to use platformStyle. You could also comment on the issueTracker and star it if you wish.

Comment: It seems like `includeFontPadding` only affects top and bottom lines of multi-line texts. After upgrading Compose to 1.3.3 there is no change in the padding for one-line texts. The documentation also doesn't include info on one-line paddings, meaning the additional height above letters instead of the line height

Comment: You could test by adding ```platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(includeFontPadding = false)``` to your ```style``` parameter of ```Text```. It is deprecated but at least it should remove the top and bottom inner padding.

Comment: the second Image is the result of using `platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(includeFontPadding = false)`. I can't believe there is no way of completely reducing the height padding?!

Comment: Yeah, hopefully someone will come up with a better answer... This might help: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b